# TypeScript (generics): errors of inferring types for an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have typescript@3.4.0-dev.20190228.

The work of the typescript in the following code is incomprehensible:

```ts
class Container<T = any> {
  constructor(private parent: Parent<T>) {}
}

class Parent<T = any> {
  constructor(private children: Child<T>[]) {}
}

class Child<T = any> {
  constructor(private model: T) {}
}

class Model1 {
  prop1: string = '';
  prop2: number = 123;
}

class Model2 {
  otherProp1: boolean = true;
  otherProp2: object = {};
}

const parentInstance = new Parent<Model1>([
  new Child(new Model2()), // Error --> It's OK
  new Child(new Model1()),
  new Child(new Model1()),
]);

const containerInstance = new Container<Model2>(
  new Parent([
    new Child(new Model2()), // Error --> Why!?
    new Child(new Model1()),
    new Child(new Model1()),
  ])
);
```

See also this code on [Playground TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Container%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20parent%3A%20Parent%3CT%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Parent%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20children%3A%20Child%3CT%3E%5B%5D)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20model%3A%20T)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Model1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prop1%3A%20string%20%3D%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20prop2%3A%20number%20%3D%20123%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Model2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20otherProp1%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20otherProp2%3A%20object%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20parentInstance%20%3D%20new%20Parent%3CModel1%3E(%5B%0D%0A%20%20new%20Child(new%20Model2())%2C%20%2F%2F%20Error%20--%3E%20It's%20OK%0D%0A%20%20new%20Child(new%20Model1())%2C%0D%0A%20%20new%20Child(new%20Model1())%2C%0D%0A%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20containerInstance%20%3D%20new%20Container%3CModel2%3E(%0D%0A%20%20new%20Parent(%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Child(new%20Model2())%2C%20%2F%2F%20Error%20--%3E%20Why!%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Child(new%20Model1())%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Child(new%20Model1())%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5D)%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A).

1. Why generic for `Container` ignore type `Model2` (see `containerInstance` setting)?
2. Why, when I change generic for `Parent` to `Model2`, does it affect the `Container` (see `parentInstance` setting)?
3. Why, when I change order of setting `containerInstance`, it have matters?

```ts
const containerInstance = new Container<Model2>(
  new Parent([
    new Child(new Model2()),
    new Child(new Model1()), // Error --> It's OK
    new Child(new Model1()), // Error --> It's OK
  ])
);

const parentInstance = new Parent<Model1>([
  new Child(new Model2()), // Error --> It's OK
  new Child(new Model1()),
  new Child(new Model1()),
]);
```

**Update:** I opened [issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30207)

Comment: This is a weird one.  The error seems to be in the wrong place, and I'm not sure what's causing it.   Seems like a TS bug, but ‍

Comment: Here's the smallest reproduction I can make: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20class%20C%3CT%3E%20%7Bc%3A%20T%3B%20constructor%28t%3A%20T%29%7D%0Adeclare%20class%20P%3CT%3E%20%7Bp%3A%20T%3B%20constructor%28cs%3A%20C%3CT%3E%5B%5D%29%7D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%200%20%7D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%200%20%7D%0Adeclare%20let%20b%3A%20B%0Adeclare%20let%20a%3A%20A%0A%2F%2F%20comment%20out%20next%20line%0Adeclare%20const%20x%3A%20C%3CA%3E%3B%0Anew%20P%28%5B%20new%20C%28b%29%2C%20new%20C%28a%29%5D%29)

Comment: I think you should consider filing an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues); I couldn't find an existing one (but there might be one)